# How to mount using ceph-fuse and specify IP in /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, ceph

My server configuration is as follows:

```
A ceph cluster server(10.1.1.138)
B ceph cluster server(10.1.1.54)
C ceph client (10.1.1.238)
```

I could mount using the following ceph-fuse command:

```
sudo ceph-fuse -k /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring -m 10.1.1.138:6789 /mnt/mycephfs/
```

But I don't know how to mount with /etc/fstab.

The following setting is fails.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
10.1.1.138:/    /mnt/mycephfs   fuse.ceph name=admin,secretfile=/home/ec2-user/admin.secret,noatime    0       2
sudo mount -a                -> Syntax error occured.
```

Using kernel driver mount instead of ceph-fuse is works.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
10.1.1.138:/    /mnt/mycephfs  ceph name=admin,secretfile=/home/ec2-user/admin.secret,noatime    0       2
sudo mount -a                -> success
```

IP specification can not be found even in the [official tutorial](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/kraken/cephfs/fstab/).

I don't know why there is no way to specify IP of each cluster server in official tutorial.

If it could be mount without specifying IP, I would like to know its principle.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Let me know there is something to be a hint.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I think the time arrived as you have to start to use punctuations. Look, how beautiful your post become :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this installed, so cannot test.  But the manual says you must supply an ID in the first column, and I don't see one in your attempt.  The cluster IP may be found in ceph.conf, or it is supposed to be possible to place in the DEVICE field.  So I would expect either of these to work:

If IP is in `ceph.conf`

```
id=admin    /mnt/mycephfs   fuse.ceph name=admin,secretfile=/home/ec2-user/admin.secret,noatime    0       2
```

If IP is not in `ceph.conf`, or if you want to override, then:

```
id=admin,m=10.1.1.138    /mnt/mycephfs   fuse.ceph name=admin,secretfile=/home/ec2-user/admin.secret,noatime    0       2
```

Given the ID appearing in the DEVICE field, I don't know if it needs to be in the option field at all.